# How to fix this valve?

Tags: valve

This valve below is slowly leaking. I am not what kind of valve it is. This is between main riser of the apartment building and helps stop water for my apartment. Any body have a clue about it? And also how to fix it? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It is a simple shut off valve.  Fixing is usually done by replacement with a new one.  Can try to tighten the nuts on it, carefully, but usually does not help for long.  This is a job for the landlord to do, since replacement requires shutting off water before this valve.

Comment: If it's a rental apartment and/or turning off service to this valve requires turning off other apartments,  it has to be the landlord who fixes it.  If the leaking is into your apartment you need to complain.  If it's into a shared unfinished part of the building, the landlord may opt to leave it alone.   You can try to open the valve hard all the way and tighten that stem nut gently with a wrench.  Don't overtighten it, it could break.

Answer (score 2):

A gate valve ; leaking at the stem packing , a routine maintenance item. It may be a rising or non-rising stem but repair is the same.  It would be best to shut off water pressure to the valve . Then back off the stem nut and put in more  or new packing. I put in more packing using teflon pipe dope tape , probable several to many wraps , then tighten down the stem nut ( as needed to stop leakage). The Teflon is slippery and permits the stem to rotate with reasonable effort. Tighter nut = less leakage but more turning effort. Various options such as using silicon carbide sand paper ( like 320 , 400 , 600 ) to polish stem smooth where there may have been slight corrosion. Also a chance that just tightening the nut will force the original packing to seal; very easy , worth a try.

Comment: Fully agree I have used PFTE tape but prefer PFTE string or rope some is impregnated with graphite, first try to tighten the stem nut, if that is not enough adding to the packing will seal it in 99.9% of the leaks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way anyone looking at that picture would know what that valve is for. As far as the valve leaking, where is it leaking? If it is at the stem, you could tighten the packing nut just a slight amount which would probably stop the leak. If the leak  is somewhere else please explain and show the location with an arrow pointing at the leaking area.

Comment: This should be a comment, since you're asking for clarification from the OP. Once OP responds with edits, the answer portion of this may be valid but the questions will need to be edited out.

Comment: It's pretty clear from the question that it's the main water supply shut-off valve to one apartment in a multi-unit building.

Comment: No reason for a down vote but the op did say it was a shutoff, and the possible fix was provided down vote reversed. D.George I almost let the down vote stand because of the comment, I constantly get down votes.

Comment: @Ed Beal I have never down voted anyone for their answers or comments since I have no way to determine what their thought process is or what they took from the question. I have seen so many "bone headed" answers that make no sense but that may be the way some people see the question or feel that that is how they would fix it. Anyway, thanks for the reversal of the down vote and yes I let my pride in being able to correct most any problem get in the way of someone else's comment or vote.